# Going back to the 'beginning' using the history api

Tags: javascript, history.js

Assuming I have an arbitrary point in my history (the point someone lands on my page), I would like to push some states as they do certain actions, and then when they are done I want to go **back** to the history point they were at when they landed on the page. So if they press forward, they are starting the actions again, and if they press back they go back to wherever they were before they landed on my page.

Now the problem is when I push states and then at one point they press back. E.g.

- landing page
- push state 1
- push state 2
- back

Now at this point if I want to return them to the landing page I only have to go back once (as opposed to twice). How do I calculate how far to send them back using javascript? It seems that history.length is pretty inconsistent, and using history.js' saved states doesn't work since a state gets added to that regardless of whether I use push state or whether they click back.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go to a particular url,just redirect to the specific url using `window.location.replace(url)`.

In your case, on all page loads,increment a counter which is kept in session variable so it is not lost between postbacks and use it  `window.history.go(-count)` to go back.

For further reading-
http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/database/hit-cntr-asp4-cs/

Comment: Just redirecting to a url doesn't achieve at all what I am trying to do, if I could just redirect the page I wouldn't be using the history api. My entire question was asking how I get that count when the back button was used. Did you read my question fully?

Comment: Again, how do you rectify that count when they use the back button. If I maintain a count of page views, when they click back I need to remove one from that count. I've given an example of this in my question (now edited to make it a bit clearer)

Comment: @rbhalla What is needed here is a Session object on the server to store the states. You can also look at various client-side storage options.http://www.cio.com/article/2382838/enterprise-browsers/4-client-side-web-storage-options-that-replace-cookies.html